# Unable to write to Db using cursor.execute() in Django - Boolean value of this clause is not defined error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a user registration form with Django. I have created a function like this:

```
def create_user(user_dict):
    from django.db import connection
    from sqlalchemy.sql import text
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

    if 'middle_name' not in user_dict:
        user_dict['middle_name'] = None
    if 'alt_email' not in user_dict:
        user_dict['alt_email'] = None
    if 'alt_mobile' not in user_dict:
        user_dict['alt_mobile'] = None
    if 'role' not in user_dict:
        user_dict['role'] = None 
    password = make_password(user_dict['password'])
    user_dict['password'] = password

    insert_query = """
    insert into user_info (first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, mobile, alt_email, alt_mobile, password, role )
        values(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :email, :mobile, :alt_email, :alt_mobile, :password, :role)
    """
    insert_query_text = text(insert_query)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(insert_query_text, user_dict)
    return(True)
```

When I call this function, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\myproject\boards\views.py", line 84, in register_user
    create_user(body)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\myproject\boards\methods.py", line 115, in create_user
    cursor.execute(insert_query_text, user_dict)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Documents\django\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 522, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

This same function works fine when I run it with Jupyter Notebook with an SQLAlchemy engine.

If it matters, all the values I'm passing are strings.

*P.S.: This is a hobby project and I'm avoiding Django built in models on purpose, not because I am not aware of them.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem psycopg2 does not support the `:parameter` format, which was what could have caused the error.

In the end, I did not need to import sqlalchemy or psycopg2 separately, and I was able to use Django's connection object to execute the query like so:

```
from django.db import connection

### same code as question ###

insert_query = """
        insert into user_info (first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, mobile,
                                alt_email, alt_mobile, password, role)
            values(%(first_name)s, %(middle_name)s, %(last_name)s, %(email)s, 
                  %(mobile)s, %(alt_email)s, %(alt_mobile)s, %(password)s, %(role)s)
        """

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(insert_query, user_dict)
            connection.commit()
```

The advantage of this approach, rather than using plain %s, is that you can pass None as the value if you don't have a value for any column. This is handled properly and doesn't result in an error. It's also easier to keep track of what value you are passing for which column.